# Presenting MFMailComposeViewController with attachment from UIActivityViewController in swift

Tags: swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

Does anyone know how I can show an MFMailComposeViewController view with attachment in Swift from UIActivityViewController I can't seem to figure it out. my app crashes

> '-[MFMailComposeInternalViewController
> addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:] attachment must not be nil.'

`let pdfDocument = NSData(contentsOf: receiptURL)

```
    let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self, pdfDocument], applicationActivities: nil)

    activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivity.ActivityType.copyToPasteboard]
    present(activityVC, animated: true)`
```

`extension ViewController: UIActivityItemSource {

```
func activityViewControllerPlaceholderItem(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> Any {
    return ""
}

func activityViewController(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController, itemForActivityType activityType: UIActivity.ActivityType?) -> Any? {
    return UIImage()
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func activityViewControllerLinkMetadata(_ activityViewController: UIActivityViewController) -> LPLinkMetadata? {
    
    let metadata = LPLinkMetadata()
    metadata.title = "Title"
    let amount = "$10"
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: amount)
    metadata.originalURL = url
    if let icon = UIImage(named: "image" ?? "") {
        metadata.imageProvider = NSItemProvider(object: icon)
    }
    
    return metadata
    
}
```

}`

Comment: What's your code? `data` parameter is nil?

Comment: Edit your question with that code. In comments, it's not readable at all...

Comment: You put `self` in `acivityItems`? What's the class of `self`? It's a UIViewController? Why include it?

Comment: I was also using LinkPresentation with it